# Behaviour of .end() when used with .before()

Tags: detach, jquery, jquery-end

When having called `.before` on elements that are detached from the DOM, `.end` behaves differently than it does with attached elements:

```
var $div1 = $("div");
console.log($div1.after("foo").end());  // [document]
$div1.detach();
console.log($div1.after("foo").end());  // [<div></div>]
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R2uc7/2/)

Apparently, `.before` causes different behaviour to `.end` depending on the node being attached or detached. I don't see the logic and I'm not sure what I can rely on.

Could someone enlighten me on the defined behaviour of `.end` combined with `.before`?

Comment: You can't insert something before something that is not in the dom. I am surprised it even does anything, the [dom equivalent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML#Visualization_of_position_names) would just fail silently.

Comment: @Esailija "As of jQuery 1.4, .before() and .after() will also work on disconnected DOM nodes.".

Comment: @meze In some kind of hacky way they do work yes, the elements are still completely disconnected from each other though and only give an illusion of working because they happen to be wrapped by the same jQuery object. Nothing was actually inserted before or after.

Comment: To proove it's not working you can simply run: `$("<div>").before("<a>").prev()` which returns an empty jQuery object even though it should return the `a` element. `$("<div>").appendTo("body").before("<a>").prev()` works normally. So it actually doesn't work.

Comment: @Esailija still, it's legal in jquery. `sibilings` works with DOM tree and we're talking about detached nodes. I don't understand why `$("<div>").after('<p></p>').filter('p').end()` works and `$("<div>").after('<p></p>').end()` does not...

Comment: @Esailija: You're correct. As I understand it, the solution is to wrap the detached node, so that the "before" concept can be realized since there is now a reference node. That would cause the same branch for both cases in zzzzBov's extract, because there's a `parentNode`. Is that correct?

Comment: @pimvdb he's wrong on before/after. The docs say `before()` and `after()` can work on detached nodes.

Comment: @meze: He's not saying anything wrong as far as I'm concerned. I think I'm getting it though - with detached nodes, only the set is changed, and `.filter` looks at the new stack so that works. `.siblings` doesn't look at the stack but at the tree. This fails because there is no parent node, so there can't be a concept of "siblings".

Comment: @pimvdb but it doesn't explain why `end` gives unexpected result. Sure you can't use DOM tree functions on disconnected nodes.

Comment: @meze: Implicitly it does: `.end` merely pops the stack. Since `.before` only changes the stack for detached nodes, `.end` pops a different item from the stack in that case than it does for attached nodes.

Comment: @pimvdb yes, `.after` and `.before` are only legit if the subject has a parent. Don't count on jQuery's attempts at trying to make it work because it just gives you false hope. `[document.createElement("div"),document.createElement("div")]`: doesn't mean they are siblings or related in any way to each other.

Comment: @pimvdb why are they only legit if the subject has a parent? .after and .before works with some limitations, but they still can be used without parents.

Comment: @meze: Think of the definition of "`.before`" and "siblings": Siblings are siblings because they share their parent. One node is before another node in that they are at the same level and connected to each other via their parent. Without a parent, you cannot place one node before another; they have no connection after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery v1.7.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) uses [`pushStack`](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack) to build the new DOM elements.

`pushStack` adds items to the jQuery object's stack (go figure!), and [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end) pops the last one off, returning the rest of the stack (whatever remains).

---

jQuery v1.7.2 line #5860:
<sub>annotation mine</sub>

```
before: function() {
    if ( this[0] && this[0].parentNode ) {
        return this.domManip(arguments, false, function( elem ) {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore( elem, this );
        });
    } else if ( arguments.length ) {
        var set = jQuery.clean( arguments );
        set.push.apply( set, this.toArray() ); 
        return this.pushStack( set, "before", arguments ); //pushStack in use
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains "how". So actually the issue is bigger, since *any* function that depends on the stack behaves differently between the two cases, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/R2uc7/4/. Is this behaviour reliable? It seems a bit odd.

Comment: @pimvdb, "it seems a bit odd" just remember that jQuery was written by people and that they sometimes make mistakes. It's hard to tell if this sort of behavior is intentional, or whether it's simply an extreme case.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I understand that :) Just had a hard time debugging this. Anyway, what I didn't take into account is the difference between the jQuery set and the actual siblings which caused confusion. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: [File a bug on the jQuery website](http://docs.jquery.com/How_to_Report_Bugs). They would love to hear about real bugs and you would love to hear from them directly if it's by design after all.